# How to use for-loop (in R) to run function(x) and if it returns NA, replace NA by output of function(y)?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am using the [gender](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gender/gender.pdf) package in R to identify the gender of given names in my dataset. Some of the people in my dataset have middle names, which I would like to use to my advantage. What `gender::gender()` does, is to identify the gender of names based on historical data (which is why installation of `genderdata` is required). It either returns detailed results on the degree to which a name is female/male or returns NA if there are no matches.

**Goal:** Write a function to apply `gender(x)` to a column of given names and, if it returns NA, refer to another column of middle names to apply `gender(y)` again and potentially replace those NAs with the gender identified by the second function.

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(gender)
library(genderdata)

# If you have any issues installing `gender`, try this:
devtools::install_github("ropensci/gender")
devtools::install_github("lmullen/gender-data-pkg")
```

**Here's my attempt:**

```
df <- tibble(name = "abc",
             name_alternative = "Peter")

gender_2 <- function(x, y){
  g_1 <- gender::gender(x) %>% select(gender)
  if(!is.na(g_1)){
    print(g_1)
  } else {
    g_2 <- gender::gender(y) %>% select(gender)
    print(g_2)
  }
}
```

Needless to say that it didn't work.

Here's what it should look like, using the default `gender()` function and using the new `gender_2()` function:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  name_1 name_2 gender gender_2
  <chr>  <chr>  <lgl>  <chr>   
1 abc    Peter  NA     male
```

**Edit:**
Thank you @Rui for your answer. This is indeed what I needed and was looking for. Here's what `gender_2()` now looks like in my script:

```
gender_2 <- function(x, y=NULL, z=NULL){
  g_1 <- gender::gender(as.character(x), method = "ipums") %>% select(name, gender)
  if (nrow(g_1) > 0) {
    g_1 
  } else {
    if (missing(y))  {
      g_1
    } else {
      g_2 <- gender::gender(as.character(y), method = "ipums") %>% select(name, gender)
      if (nrow(g_2) > 0) {
        g_2
      } else {
        if (missing(z))  {
          g_1
        } else {
          g_3 <- gender::gender(as.character(z), method = "ipums") %>% select(name, gender)
          g_3
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: @akrun: No the point of `nrow(g_1) > 0` is to check if there is a match in the gender database. If there isn't, the output of `gender() %>% select(gender)` will just be an empty tibble. My mistake: I thought it would return NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure the following function answers the question.

```
gender_2 <- function(x, y){
  g_1 <- gender::gender(x, method = "ipums") %>% select(name, gender)
  if(nrow(g_1) > 0){
    g_1
  } else {
    gender::gender(y, method = "ipums") %>% select(name, gender)
  }
}

gender_2(df$name, df$name_alternative)
## A tibble: 1 x 2
#  name  gender
#  <chr> <chr> 
#1 Peter male
```

Comment: Thank you @Rui_Barradas, this is  what I was looking for. Also see my edited question for a slightly modified version of that function (i.e., what it looks like now in my script).